# Specific Facebook page plugin doesn't work on mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile

I came across something strange; the Facebok Page Plugin doesn't load on mobile only if it's for a specific Facebook page.

My code:

```
<div id="fb-root">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=1591121954498982";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-height="350" data-hide-cover="false" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/סיפורי-פירות-Fruit-Story/410067012494711?fref=ts" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true" data-small-header="false">&nbsp;</div>
```

Changing just this line:
`data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/סיפורי-פירות-Fruit-Story/410067012494711?fref=ts"`

to another page's URL such as:
`data-href="https://www.facebook.com/CocaColaUnitedStates?fref=ts"`

...makes the plugin load fine.
Is it because the page URL contains Hebrew? Is there a relevant page setting?

I set up a small demo page:
http://s-fruit.co.il/facebook-test.html

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

After digging around I'm closer to a solution: it's related to not being logged into Facebook (coincidentally occurring on mobile).
However still no explanation why Coca Cola's and other plugins still work without login.

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause!

This is an intentional (though peculiar) behavior of Facebook when dealing with age-restricted pages and guest users (not logged in, as it often happens on mobile browsers as most use the app).

Why not simply display a login prompt? Some paraphrased info? Who knows. At least the mystery is solved.

An official response can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/828224027247232/